# How to login within the website https://app.buenbit.com/dashboard using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

im stuck trying to input email and pass on a web page. I toke xpath from email input but when I execute the code I get a error in the consol.

```
  import time
from datetime import date
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
browser.get('https://app.buenbit.com/dashboard')

usuario = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[1]/input')


browser.quit()
```

this is the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:/proyectos/SCRAPY/MercadoLibre HIDE.py", line 12, in 
>       usuario = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[1]/input')
>     File "C:\Users\vrodrig5\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
>     File "C:\Users\vrodrig5\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
>       return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
>     File "C:\Users\vrodrig5\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\vrodrig5\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[1]/input"}
>     (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

Answer (score 1):

To login within the website https://app.buenbit.com/ using a valid set of credentials you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://app.buenbit.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']"))).send_keys("Victor_Rodriguez")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://app.buenbit.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']"))).send_keys("Victor_Rodriguez")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: buenbit]

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```